# Something wrong with call function

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know where does it goes wrong. I can get the correct result if I just call out my valid_ISBN(isbn) function, but when I write the file, the result become all invalid. (maybe something wrong with function call, but I don't know how to fix it)

```
def main():
    # Call and open the File
    inFile = open("isbn.txt", "r")

    for line in inFile:
        line_strip = line.replace("-", "").replace(" ", "").rstrip("\n")
        isbn = line_strip # the function call

        # Output file
       str = []
       str.append(line)
        outFile = open("isbnOut.txt", "a")
        for i in str:
            if valid_ISBN(isbn) == "valid":
                outFile.write(i.strip() + "  valid\n")
            else:
                outFile.write(i.strip() + "  invalid\n")



    inFile.close()
    outFile.close()

def valid_ISBN(isbn):
    if len(isbn) != 10 or (isbn[0:9].isdigit()) == False:
        print("invalid")
    else:
        return partial_sums(isbn)

def partial_sums(s1):
    lst1 =[]
    sum1 = 0
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if (i == (len(s1) -1)) and ((s1[i] == "x") or (s1[i] == "X")):
            sum1 = sum1 + 10
        else:
            sum1 = sum1 + int(s1[i])
        lst1.append(sum1)
    #print(lst1)

    sum_of_s1(lst1)

def sum_of_s1(s2):
    lst2 = []
    sum2 = 0
    for i in s2:
        sum2 += i
       lst2.append(sum2)
    #print(lst2)

    checkISBN(lst2[-1])

def checkISBN(value):
    if value % 11 == 0:
        print("valid")
    else:
        print("invalid")


main()
```

2 Test case for isbn text file (no new line):

019-923-3241

818-851-703X

Answer (score 0):

In your main function:

Every time you read a line in from your input file you initialize str and fill it with just one value. You open your output file, do your validity checks for your one value in str, and finally write the one value to the the output file.

The next time you read the file you do the same stuff... so str isn't needed at all

Also using `str` as a variable name is bad form. In your console write in `help(str)` and you will see why.

Now to deal with your actual complaint:

Your problem is the fact that there is no new line.

when you say `for line in some_open_file_handler:...` what python does is populate `line` with everything up to the next newline character or the end of the file.

If your input file has no new lines seperating isbns then the first value of line would be `019-923-3241 818-851-703X`. Thus the line `line_strip = line.replace("-", "").replace(" ", "").rstrip("\n")` set linestrip to `0199233241818851703X`

This should fix it:
`'line.split()` will yield `['019-923-3241','818-851-703X']`

```
outFile = open("isbnOut.txt", "a")
for line in open("isbn.txt", "r"):
    isbns = line.split()  #this splits stuff up by whitespace.
    for isbn in isbns: 
        isbn = isbn.replace("-", "").replace(" ", "").rstrip("\n")
        if valid_ISBN(isbn) == "valid":
            outFile.write(i.strip() + "  valid\n")
        else:
            outFile.write(i.strip() + "  invalid\n")
```